# BroadCast Receiver is not Refreshing the Data on the Change of PowerSource of Mobile Battery

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am using the BroadCastReceiver to Show the Data of the battery PowerSource by which it is providing the Data. I have used Fragment to Show the Data. I am Able to get the Data and Set it to the Required field but it is not Refreshing on the Disconnect of the PowerSource.How can this issue be Solved?

**BatteryFragment**

```
public class BatteryFragment extends Fragment{

    FragmentBatteryBinding fragmentBatteryBinding;
    BatteryFragmentVm batteryFragmentVm;
    List<PojoMain> batteryData;
    RecyclerAdapter recyclerDeviceAdapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        fragmentBatteryBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_battery, container, false);
        batteryFragmentVm = new BatteryFragmentVm(getContext());
        fragmentBatteryBinding.setBatteryVm(batteryFragmentVm);



        retrieveBatteryData(getContext());
        return fragmentBatteryBinding.getRoot();
    }





    //get Battery Power Source
    public static String isPlugged(Context context) {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);

        String powerSource = "";

        if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC) {
            powerSource = "Plugged AC";
        } else if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB) {
            powerSource = "Plugged USB";
        } else if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS) {
            powerSource = "PLugged Wireless";
        } else if (plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING) {
            powerSource = "Discharging";
        } else {
            powerSource = "status unknown";
        }

        return powerSource;
    }


    public void retrieveBatteryData(Context context) {
      //  batteryData.clear();
        batteryData = new ArrayList<>();

        batteryData.add(new PojoMain("Power Source", isPlugged(context)));


        batteryFragmentVm.loadBatteryData(batteryData)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(pojoMains -> {
                    recyclerDeviceAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(batteryData, getContext());
                    fragmentBatteryBinding.batteryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                    fragmentBatteryBinding.batteryRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerDeviceAdapter);
                });


    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


}
```

**BatteryFragmentVm**

```
public class BatteryFragmentVm {
    Context context;

    public BatteryFragmentVm(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public Observable<List<PojoMain>> loadBatteryData(List<PojoMain> string) {

        return Observable.just(string)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
    }


}
```

> Why the data received are not changed on the change of the power
>   source?How can this issue be solved?

Comment: How are you registering the `BroadcastReceiver` to get the battery updates? What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @davidwasser, i have solved it mate.

Comment: Great that you solved it. You should answer your own question because maybe your solution would help others who have a similar problem, and it would also get the question off the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @DavidWasser ok man. I will post answer.